# Naming convention for iPhone 5 images?

Tags: objective-c

I am working on an app that would be for iPhone 5 and lower.

for images I am using this code

```
CGRect mainFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

int imgIndex = arc4random() % 10 + 1;

if(mainFrame.size.height > 480)
    [pBackgroundImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"dreams 1136x640 %d.jpg",imgIndex]]];
else
    [pBackgroundImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"dreams_960x640_%d.jpg",imgIndex]]];
```

but I am not satisfied with it.

is there any specific naming convention for iphone 5 images?

Thanks in advance
Mano

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Default-568h@2x.png` this would be the launch image you need, you need to add `-568h@2x` to the end of all your iPhone 5 images, but there have been issues with the naming convention.

I found doing it like this has helped.

```
   [pBackgroundImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:(IS_PHONE5()) ? @"myimage-568h@2x.png" : @"myimage.png"]];
```

The issue is it doesn't pick the `-568h@2x` up but this is the way it should be.
to get the `IS_PHONE5` variable add

```
   #define IS_PHONE5() ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568.0f && [UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.f && UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
```

Thought this may help anyone wondering about supporting high resolution phones and iPhone 5

[Supporting high resolution and iPhone 5](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreensInViews/SupportingHiResScreensInViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH15-SW1)