# Screen size of iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm developing the app to work both on iphone4 and iPhone 5. I'm using the following code to get the screen size

```
  CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

[image]

am using the iPhone 5 simulator but it showing the screen size of iPhone 4.

Comment: Are you sure, I've just check it and it does not show the same size. 4" retina : `(CGRect) screenBounds = origin=(x=0, y=0) size=(width=320, height=568)` 3,5" retina `(CGRect) screenBounds = origin=(x=0, y=0) size=(width=320, height=480)`

Comment: @rckoenes:: i have posted the image

Comment: See the answer by Popeye, you are missing the `Default-568h@2x.png`. Read the Apple documentation it will tell you you need the `Default-568h@2x.png` in order to run in fullscreen mode on the 4" devices.

Comment: @rckoenes:: ok i will try with that

Comment: @rckoenes:: default-568 is for launch image right?? will that be prob??

Comment: Yes just like the answer by Popeye states you will need the `Default-568h@2x.png` launch image. Also read the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the simulator make sure you have set to iPhone (Retina 4-inch). 
You can do this by going simulator menu at the top go to Hardware>>Device>>iPhone (Retina 4-inch) that will change the phone simulator to the iPhone 5 version.

If this is set then you may need to add a launch image for the iPhone 5. `Default-568h@2x.png` if this is missing it will not launch in iPhone (Retina 4-inch).

I have also answer another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287047/naming-convention-for-iphone-5-images/13287481#13287481) that may help.

Comment: :: i posted the output image can you check

Comment: @downvoter why the downvote this is a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

When running the simulator, go to `Hardware` -> `Device` and make sure that `iPhone (Retina 4-inch)` is selected.

Comment: ya iphone retina 4 inch is selected

Answer (score 0):

In fact

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height
```

returns 568 for iPhone 5. Make sure, you selected "iPhone 4 - (4 inch)" as Device in the Simulator (it's there since Xcode 4.5). There should also be an Default-568h@2x.png file in your project if you created your project using the Xcode assistent.