# Does the iPhone 5's screen require separate versions of my app's images?

Tags: ios, graphics, retina-display, iphone-5

I have a graphic designer that creates images and things like that for me. Do I need give him separate image sizes to be created specifically for iPhone 5, or do I build like I used to for the 3.5 inch screen? Will the images be resized automatically?

Comment: It depends upon what the image is. If it's just a background texture, you can get away with just have your graphics team design a single bigger image which you can then center and not scale it (e.g. use `contentMode` of `UIViewContentModeCenter`). If it's a button that won't be growing, you obviously don't have to do anything. But in general, if the graphical element is changing size, it's prudent to have resources for the appropriate sizes. And almost as important as the 3.5" v 4.0" screen, you'll want retina resolution assets to really optimize the experience on retina devices.

Comment: @Rob Thank you Rob for that detailed explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one link that may help you.

[Naming convention for iPhone 5 images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287047/naming-convention-for-iphone-5-images/13287481#13287481)

and  heres another

[Screen size of iphone 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399075/screen-size-of-iphone-5/13399220#13399220)

Reviewing these links basically evaluates to yes you have to create separate images for iPhone 5 you will need to add `-568h@2x.png` to the end of each image that is for iPhone 5. You need to also create and set the launch image as well called `Default-568h@2x.png` are it will not pick anything up for the iPhone 5.

No it will not resize the images automatically it will select the correct image to use, it will select the one with the `-568h@2x.png` simple as that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Popeye. So is the answer Yes? I am aware how to use iPhone 5 in the simulator.  I have seen that code that "re-sizes" views but will that re-size images nicely? Thanks

Comment: A non-retina image designed for a 3.5" screen can look horrible on iPhone 5. I'd definitely lean towards separate assets for the different devices.

Comment: Yes same I would just create 3 images. One for iPhone 3GS, One for iPhone 4/4S and one for iPhone 5. Excluding iPad.

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide specific files if your images are dependent on the screen ratio.

In order to conditionally use an image according to the device you can use the technique shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287047/naming-convention-for-iphone-5-images/13287481#13287481).

If that's not the case, simply provide the same images and adjust the layout programmatically or within Interface Builder.

Answer (score 2):

No iOS devices with a retina display can run iOS 3. You will need high resolution versions of all your pictures.

As for converting photos to work with the iPhone 5, it depends on the photo and how it's used. If the image is used as part of the background, you have two options: you can tile it, which would not require new pictures, or you will have to redesign it altogether.

As for the other pictures, whether you can work with the same ones (same size or resized) or need new ones depends on user interface decisions only you can make. If an image must retain a certain ratio, then perhaps you can resize it and place it accordingly, or maybe an entire new image would work better.