# Support Retina 4-inch with a deployment target to 4.3

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

I'm developing an iPhone and iPad app with latest SDK and Xcode 4.5.2.

My client said me that the app has to support iOS 4.3 and above.

So, if I target iOS 4.3 I can't use:

- Storyboards.
- Auto-layouts.

I have to create XIB for every `ViewController`, but:

**What must I do to support Retina 4-inch screen?**

and

**What must I do something to support iOS 5?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply design your app for 3.5" screens, and make judicous use of autoresizing masks.

Comment: This is the simplest way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Above all, it's the only way if you need to support iOS 4.3.

Answer (score 0):

For supporting Retina 4-inch screen, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396545/ios-6-apps-how-to-deal-with-iphone-5-screen-size) is good answer to that

and YES Storyboards and Auto-layouts are not for iOS 4.3

More on iOS 5, you don't need to do and special coding for that

and YES you can support Retina 4 inch with deployment target set to iOS 4.3

Hope this info helps you..

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I want to know how can I support Retina 4 inch display, Retina 3.5 inch display and 3.5 inch display. Will I need to add two xibs, one for Retina 4 inch and the other one for the others display?

Comment: @VansFannel I would do this in code and not actually on the xibs. So I would have something like `if(IS_IPHONE5()) { // do one layout } else if(IS_IPAD) { // do this layout } else {// do the final layout}`

Comment: No, you dont need to create separate xib for Retina 4 inch. You can do this in code. Visit the link above which I have made hyperlink. Here you will find all solution to handle code for Retina 4 inch display..

Comment: @Prateek I'm testing it now.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these two links

[Screen size of iphone 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399075/screen-size-of-iphone-5/13399220#13399220)

[Naming convention for iPhone 5 images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287047/naming-convention-for-iphone-5-images/13287481#13287481)

I don't see why these wouldn't work.

**Move from comments**

@VansFannel I would do this in code and not actually on the xibs. So I would have something like

```
   if(IS_IPHONE5()) { 
      // do one layout 
   } else if(IS_IPAD) { 
      // do this layout 
   } else {
      // do the final layout
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In info.plist file remove the option of Launch screen interface file base name and you wont get the issue