# Make iPhone App Compatible with iphone 5

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, iphone-5

I had submitted my App to App store and it got rejected.

Reason for rejection is app not compatible with iPhone 5.

> iPhone 5 Optimization Requirement - Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5. As of May 1, all new iPhone apps and app updates submitted must support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5. All apps must include a launch image with the -568h size modifier immediately following the portion of the launch image's filename. Launch images must be PNG files and located at the top-level of your bundle, or provided within each .lproj folder if you localize your launch images. Learn more about iPhone 5 support and app launch images by reviewing the iOS Human Interface Guidelines and iOS App Programming Guide.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399075/screen-size-of-iphone-5/13399220#13399220 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287047/naming-convention-for-iphone-5-images/13287481#13287481

Comment: You forgot to add the default images for the startup for iPhone-5 according to the rejection notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to Update Your Apps for the 4-Inch iPhone 5 Display](http://www.raywenderlich.com/33150/how-to-update-your-apps-for-the-4-inch-iphone-5-display) is a good tutorial.

Also do not forget to Add a -568h launch image.

Answer (score 2):

Add a Default-568h@2x.png launch image.

Set your main window frame to the UIScreen mainScreen bounds in your app delegate.

If everything else in your code sizes itself to the size of your views, there shouldn't be much else to do