# ios app not fitting iphone 5 screen

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, screen

[image]My ios app does not fit on iphone 5 screen. When I run the app, I can see blank space at the top and bottom of the screen. I have made the app compatible for both iphone sizes. But Since I have updated to the latest xcode, I am facing this issue. See screen shot. Can any one please help?

Comment: Have you included the Default-562@2x.png launch image? Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399075/screen-size-of-iphone-5/13399220#13399220

Comment: Because your application is only built(Developed) for iPhone4 & 4S(3.5-Inch Display) not for iPhone5 (4-Inch Display), create your application compatible to iPhone5, then it will show you in full screen.

Comment: yes. But I dont think this is related to that.

Comment: its developed for both. I have been running it on both devices. The previous version of the app is on the app store. I have just modified the UI and updated to the latest xcode

Comment: You might have linked the iPhone4/4S views to the iPhone5 build. Since you are creating an app for both builds you might have placed some checks wrong.

Comment: I would recommend a clean build if you have included the Default-562h@2x.png missing this out is the only thing I have ever heard of for the reason behind your app running like this.

Comment: i have tried that. does not work

Comment: Can you include an image of all your launch images in the image.assests folder please.

Answer (score 4):

You probably may not have set your Default-568h image.

Answer (score 1):

On the simulator make sure you have set to iPhone (Retina 4-inch). 
You can do this by going simulator menu at the top go to Hardware->Device->iPhone (Retina 4-inch) that will change the phone simulator to the iPhone 5 version.

click here for more get information for naming convention of images [here][Naming convention for iPhone 5 images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287047/naming-convention-for-iphone-5-images/13287481#13287481) [here]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting AutoresizingMask to your container views instead of assigning appFrame.
I have faced the same problem while moving to iOS 7. 
Solution comes with AutoresizingMask. iOS 7 has full Screen layout for ViewControllers.